# SpringBoot Service performance different when tested directly vs through another service

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

we are getting a weird issue and we are not able to identify what can be the root cause. Our service is written using Sprint boot and we are connecting to MariaDB through JPA.

- If we do performance test of our service directly hitting the service end point (returning list of records) we get **300ms** performance for **40 tps** load
- If we do performance test with the same load **40 tps** through an experience api which consumes our service through feign client we get performance of **5 seconds**

Interestingly from our service logs the difference we see above **is while opening the db connection and executing query in our service**. We are confused why with two different ways of hitting the same service the db performance differs. Has anyone faced similar issue before or has any suggestions to debug?

Comment: How about network latency?

Comment: and 5 seconds is average response time of your API ?

Comment: Network latency is constant between both tests i.e. both are in the same region, also majority of the time when cosumed through experience api is not in network latency but in database query which happens only in one api

Comment: @VeKe - no the api response time is 300 ms but when someone who is consuming us do perf testing it's coming as 5 seconds

Comment: What do you mean by API end point? The controller? Or are you doing actual HTTP requests? What SQL statement get executed in both cases?

Comment: @JensSchauder - I mean HTTP request. It's a select statement which is execute over .5 million records.

Comment: If you are executing the exact same SQL statements and they take 15 times longer it is a database issue. Check the internals of your database for any resource issues.